# Can multilevel meta analysis be random-effects model and/or fixed effects model?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am learning `multilevel meta-analysis` (or, `three-level meta-analysis` e.g., https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/mlma.html, and [Three-Level Multilevel Meta-analysis: What exactly are the three levels? Multilevel vs. Multilevel SEM Approaches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350629/three-level-multilevel-meta-analysis-what-exactly-are-the-three-levels-multile)) and trying to deeply understand how this new relatively new approach fits into the more commonly used general meta-analysis (or two-level meta-analyses) in relation to weighting.

For the general meta-analysis model, I learned that there are two different models based on the effect size weighting: `fixed-effects model` and `random-effects model`, the former uses the inverse variance weighting of `sampling variance` and the latter uses the inverse variance weighting of `sampling variance` plus `tau^2` (i.e., between-study variances).

When talking about multilevel meta-analysis models, I've personally never heard that people discuss a model being `fixed-effects` or `random-effects`. I realized that `metafor` does not allow us to specify a fixed-effects model when running multilevel meta-analysis (although we can choose  `ML` or `REML` for `method`). So, I am wondering if multilevel meta-analysis is theoretically a `random-effects model`?

So, my question is, Can we also call multilevel meta-analysis models either (i) fixed-effects model or (ii) random-effects model, based on the approach of weighting?

I would appreciate it if I could hear any perspectives, or where I can further read into, and parts that I am not understanding correctly if any.